# Is there any way to upload/export the test result from excel to MTM through automation.?

Tags: selenium, tfs, specflow, microsoft-test-manager

I want to upload my automation test result (Pass/Fail) from excel sheet to MTM .  This should be done through automation as well.  i.e.

When ever i run my automation scripts manually in my machine , its result is stored in the excel sheet. With that at the end of the test run , the result should get exported from excel to the MTM , where i have a column called test case result.   I dont want to do the upload part manually, it should be done in the automation as well.   Can any one suggest me this ?  i am completely new at this part.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you explain a little about what MTM is? I haven't run into that acronym before.

Comment: @GregBurghardt  Its Microsoft Test manager. also have tagged it.